VisualStudioのソリューションエクスプローラーのファイルの入れ子
VisualStudio C#で同じ名前で拡張子の異なるファイルが２つあるのですが、
これをファイルのネストでグループ化したいのですが、どうすればできるのでしょうか？
新規作成から追加すると自動でなっているのですが、既存のファイルを追加するとバラバラになります。
一応、ソリューションエクスプローラー上にあるファイルの入れ子ボタンは有効になっています。
手順としては、

C#のWinUI３プロジェクトを作成
すでに用意していた、Test.xaml、Test.csファイルをプロジェクトフォルダ内にコピーペースト
自動でソリューションエクスプローラーに追加されますが、特にグループ化はなっていない。


ファイルの入れ子ボタンは有効

グループ化している場合

※プロジェクトファイル内で各ファイルにDependentUponを設定すれば階層構造になるのは知っていますが、もっと自動でならないのだろうかという質問です。

こちらの記事に書かれている内容ではありませんか？ ソリューション エクスプローラーでのファイルの入れ子 この記事のとおりに作業しても出来ないとか、何か特定のファイルでやろうとしても出来ないとかなら、具体的にそれらのファイル名やファイルの内容・ツリー構造などと行った作業の詳細を質問に提示してみてください。

ありがとうございます。そうですその記事の内容です。自分が思っていた機能とは少し違っていました。（てっきりドラッグアンドドロップでグループ化するのかと）
ぱっと読んだ感じいまいち方法が理解できませんがもう少しじっくり確認します。
また解決しましたらこちらで報告させていただきます。

ファイル名からすると単体テストのような感じですが、そういうものはテスト対象と同じプロジェクト＆フォルダに入れるのではなく、テスト用のプロジェクトを作成して別のフォルダに入れるのが普通なのでは？ 例えばこちらの記事から始まる一連の資料のように。単体テストの基本

設定方法が分かりましたので回答に投稿しました！
アドバイスありがとうございました。
ファイルはフォルダ分けしようと思います。

以下の記事の「(1) App.Debug.config と App.Release.config の追加」のセクションに書いてあるようにしたらどうなりますか？　（未検証・未確認なのでハズレだったらスミマセン）
App.Debug.config と App.Release.config を使った構成ファイル書き換え
https://surferonwww.info/blogengine/post/2024/11/10/transformation-of-configuration-file-using-debug-config-and-release-config.aspx

【追記】
未検証・未確認では何なのでちょっとやってみました。
対象は VS2022 17.12.3 のテンプレートを使ってターゲットフレームワーク .NET Framework 4.8 で作成した WPF ソリューション / プロジェクトです。
あるプロジェクトで、[追加(D)] ⇒ [新しい項目(W)...] で表示されるダイアログの中から「ユーザーコントロール (WPF)」を選んで追加します。UserControl1.xaml と UserControl1.xaml.cs という 2 つのファイルが追加されます。
Windows 付属のエクスプローラーで、その 2 つのファイルを他のソリューション / プロジェクトに追加し、VS2022 のソリューションエクスプローラーでプロジェクトに含めた結果が下の画像です。見ての通りそれだけで階層表示されます。質問者さんの場合そうならないとのことですが、どうやったのですか？　ひょっとして、もともとのプロジェクトを .NET 8.0 とかで作ったとか？

プロジェクトファイルは以下の画像のようになっています。自分のをチェックしてください。同じように設定してみたらどうなりますか？


ご確認ありがとうございます。わたしが行ったのは、ソースのフォルダに直接csファイルとxamlファイルをコピーペーストしたものです。[追加(D)] ⇒ [新しい項目(W)...] で表示されるダイアログの中から追加したものではありません。　設定ファイルを作成しての確認がまだできていないのですが確認しましたらこちらにてコメントさせていただきます！

その「csファイルとxamlファイル」をどうやって作ったんですか？　上に書いたように正しく作れば正しい結果になりますよ。私の想像の斜め上のことをしてるように思えますけど。

ファイルは別のところからコピー＆ペーストで置いたものです。
また原因が分かりました。ファイル名がtest.xaml, test.csとしておりましたが、
csファイルの方を、test.xaml.csにするとネストされるようになりました。

クローズしてください

解決しましたのでこちらにて書きます。
まずネストされていなかったのはファイル名が原因でした、
ファイル名がtest.xaml, test.csとしておりましたが、
csファイルの方を、test.xaml.csにするとネストされるようになりました。
これで自分のしたいことは解決しましたが、任意のルールでネストする方法もコメントで教えていただいたドキュメントで分かりましたのでここに書きます。

設定例

ソリューションエクスプローラーでソリューションを右クリックすると、ファイルの入れ子＞ソリューション設定の追加、でソリューションに設定ファイルが生成されます。
.filenesting.jsonを編集して以下のように書くとネストされるようになります。


{
  "help": "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866610",
  "root": true,

  "dependentFileProviders": {
    "add": {
      "extensionToExtension": {
        "add": {
          ".cs": [
            ".xaml"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



「任意のルールでネストする方法もコメントで教えていただいたドキュメントで分かりました」というのはターゲットフレームワークが .NET の話ですよね。（.NET Framework ではなくて）

はいそうです。このサイトのことです。
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer?view=vs-2022

最初は .NET or .NET Framework どちらの話だったのでしょう？　質問に書いてあった「プロジェクトファイル内で各ファイルにDependentUponを設定すれば階層構造になるのは知っています」ということから  .NET Framework の話だと思ったのですが。何にせよ、質問する際最初にターゲットフレームワークを明確にしておいていただけたらと思います。

余計なお世話かもしれませんが、Windows OS 上で動かす Windows Forms アプリとか WPF アプリを、特に理由がない限り、ターゲットフレームワーク .NET で作ることは考えない方が良いと思います。.NET には、特定の OS に依存する機能は Visual Studio のテンプレートで作るプロジェクトには含まれてないとか（例: GDI+ に依存するグラフィックス機能、エンコーディングの Shift_JIS）、ReportViewer や Chart が使えないとか、データソース構成ウィザードが使えないとか、Visual Studio のデザイナが対応してないとか、乗り越えなければならない壁があります。Web アプリですと、ASP.NET Web Forms アプリは全く対応できないという絶対に乗り越えられない壁があります。サポート期間の長さを気にしてということなら、.NET 8.0 の 2026年 11 月 10 日より .NET Framework 4.8.1 の「サポートされているバージョンの Windows にインストールされている限り」の方が長いはずです。
